# Term for locations where a function is positive

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

If $f$ is a real valued function of $n$ real variables, what is the term for the subset of the domain of $f$ where $f \ge 0$?

Comment: You can write $f^{-1}(\left[0,\infty\right))$

Comment: The positive set or non-negative set of $f$? Don't know if this is the standard term but I think it's informative enough.

Comment: @Holo $f^{-1}$ is the preimage; not the inverse

Answer (score 1):

If $D \subset \mathbb R^n$ is the domain of $f$, then the subset in question is given by

$$\{x \in D: f(x) \ge 0\}.$$

Comment: Indeed, but I was wondering if there was a term. For instance, if I was only interested in where $f \ne 0$, if be looking for f's support. Is there a similar term for this case?

Comment: $\{x \in D: f(x) \ne 0\}.$